# How do I set the storage options in docker-compose v3?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker Compose version 2 has a store_opts key. Docker compose 3 does not.

> https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/

I want to set the storage options of docker-compose to use the `inmemory` driver, because I'm using docker-compose for unit testing a database. How can I set the storage driver in docker-compose v3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to set `inmemory`, you can use `type: tmpfs` with `driver_opts` and mount it to your container:

```
version: '3'
services:
    database:
        image: postgres
        tty: true
        ports:
          - "5432"
        volumes:
          - "mypartition:/path/to/my/partition"
          - "/your/custom/path:/any/other/location"
volumes:
    mypartition:
      driver_opts:
        type: tmpfs
        o: "size=2g"
        device: tmpfs
```

Answer (score 1):

You can view the [Docker compose volume spec](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#volumes-top-level-element) of docker compose version 3.

You can specify the driver and driver_opts under the volume section.

For example, volume section will look like :

```
volumes:
  example:
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
```

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and use `version: '2.4'` in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

Version 3's options are a little more oriented towards Docker's Swarm cluster manager.  Several of the version 2 options, especially around resource settings, are removed in version 3, and then put into a `deploy:` block which is ignored in non-Swarm mode.

Version 2 is still fully supported by all versions of the `docker-compose` tool, and if you need version 2 options then the recommended approach is to use a version 2 Compose file.